# How to vertical align using vh?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical align a h1 inside a div that uses min-height in vh units. 
Here is the html and the css:
**HTML**

```
 <section class="imgdestaque">
  <h1>Abraçar o <span>Ar Puro</span></h1>
 </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgdestaque{
width:100%;
min-height:75vh;
background: url(../img/destaque2.jpg) no-repeat left bottom fixed;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
margin-top:50px;}

.imgdestaque h1{
color: white;
font-family: 'museosans900';
font-size:5em;
padding-top:15%;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;}
```

It really looks off when you see it on mobile or reduce the height of the browser. Any solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for this, one is the example below.

```css
.imgdestaque {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 75vh;
  background: url(../img/destaque2.jpg) no-repeat left bottom fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.imgdestaque h1 {
  color: red;
  font-family: 'museosans900';
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/* This centers your h1 tag vertically */

.imgdestaque {
  position: relative;
}
.imgdestaque h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="imgdestaque">
  <h1>Abraçar o <span>Ar Puro</span></h1>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried that but the text is no longer centered and when I resize the window in height, the problem presists. See how it looks: http://imgur.com/2f0ouFJ